# grok help for logstash2

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

My logs look as such (IIS Full Log)

```
2015-03-12 16:46:33 W3SVC1 TESTPC 192.168.50.4 GET / - 443 - 217.20.181.177 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/40.0.2214.115+Safari/537.36 - - hideme.ru 200 0 0 1449 402 187
```

I have a problem with format httpversion (looks like HTTP/1.1). I don't know how to format it

I used the following formatting simply by using the grok patterns page.

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:sitename} %{NOTSPACE:whost} %{IPORHOST:hostip} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:page} %{NOTSPACE:query} %{NUMBER:port} %{NOTSPACE:username} %{IPORHOST:clientip} %{GREEDYDATA:httpversion} %{NOTSPACE:useragent} %{NOTSPACE:cookie} %{NOTSPACE:referrer} %{WORD:host} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:substatus} %{NUMBER:scstatus} %{NUMBER:csbytes} %{NUMBER:timetaken}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get at the http version part (1.1 for your HTTP/1.1) you can do the following (taken from [logstash-patterns-core](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/tree/master/patterns), COMMONAPACHELOG):

```
HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}
```